# Merging Table A and B using only columns from Table A in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes A and B where columns in A are subset of columns in B like the following

Table A:

```
[A] [B] [C]
 1   2   3
 4   5   6
```

Table B:

```
[A] [B] [C] [D]
 7   8   9  10
11  12  13  14
```

I wish to get the output like this:

```
[A] [B] [C]
 1   2   3
 4   5   6
 7   8   9
11  12  13
```

What kind of code/function should I use to directly get such result?

I tried `rbind.fill` but I got all the distinct columns from A and B that I can drop some of them later. 
However, my actual data contains so many columns that it wouldn't be optimal to simply type down all the unneeded columns.

If it's really unwise trying to get the result I want in one go, other quick workarounds are welcomed =D. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the columns in `B` which are present in `A` and then `rbind` those columns.

```
cols <- names(B)[names(B) %in% names(A)] 
rbind(A, B[cols])

#   A  B  C
#1  1  2  3
#2  4  5  6
#3  7  8  9
#4 11 12 13
```

If both `A` and `B` can have different columns, we can use `intersect` to find common columns

```
cols <- intersect(names(B), names(A))
rbind(A[cols], B[cols])
```

**data**

```
A <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L), B = c(2L, 5L), C = c(3L, 6L)), class 
= "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
B <- structure(list(A = c(7L, 11L), B = c(8L, 12L), C = c(9L, 13L), 
D = c(10L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **tidyverse** you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(a, b[names(a)])
```

Or

```
bind_rows(a, b %>% select(names(a))
```

**Generating data**

```
a <- tribble(
    ~A, ~B, ~C,
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
)

b <- tribble(
    ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
    7,8,9,10,
    11,12,13,14
)
```